# Autodesk Forge Webhooks API publish completed webhook

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

Is there a webhook that notifies that a model publish operation has been **completed** (succeeded/failed)?

I found a [webhook](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/model.publish) that notifies that the operation has started. However, it is not useful for me because I need to copy the model to another directory after the operation is completed and the model is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/model.publish/#callback-payload) of the `model.publish` event, the `payload.state` property in the webhook callback represents:

> Reason why the notification was triggered. Possible values are PUBLISHING_PENDING and PUBLISHING_IN_PROGRESS.

> Note: There is no PUBLISHING_COMPLETE state. Use the dm.version.added event to receieve notifications when publishing is finished.

So, consider using the [dm.version.added](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/dm.version.added/) event.

Comment: Thank you for your help Petr. I used the dm.version.added webhook, and It was triggered after the publishing process was completed.